# Python Asyncio: how to read from odbc and write to file at the same time?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to load data from **odbc** and write to file at the same time using **python** and **ayncio** without much luck yet.

I have batchs of `200 000` rows coming from the **odbc** and I'd like to start writing to the *filesystem* as soon as one of the batch finishes reading. I'd like the *write* to start writting without blocking the *read* of the next batch but so far the writting happens at the very end instead of conccurently while reading.

```
async def writeToCsv_v5(list_tables_source):
     # start=time.time()
     connection_string='Driver=Progress OpenEdge 12.2 Driver;HOST=bla;DB=bla;PORT=9000;UID=bla;PASSWORD=bla'

     for table in list_tables_source:
          list_columns=' ,'.join(f'"{item}"' for item in  list_tables_source[table] )
          reader = read_arrow_batches_from_odbc(
               query='Select  '+list_columns+' from PUB."'+table+'"',
               connection_string=connection_string,
               batch_size=200000,
               max_text_size=500,
          )
          
          i=0
          list_task=[]
          for batch in reader:
            read_start=time.time()
             # Process arrow batches
            df = batch.to_pandas()
            read_stop=time.time()
            list_task.append(asyncio.create_task(write_to_parquet_v1(df,i)))
            print("Time to read "+str(1)+"batch is :"+str(read_stop-read_start))
            i+=1
          print("finish read")
     await asyncio.gather(*list_task)

async def write_to_parquet_v1(df: pd.DataFrame,i: int):
     print("Start taks : "+str(i))
     df=df.applymap(str)
     write_start=time.time()
     df.to_parquet(path+table+"_"+str(i)+".parquet",engine='fastparquet')
     write_stop=time.time()
     print("Time to write to file "+str(1)+"batch is :"+str(write_stop-write_start))

asyncio.run(writeToCsv_v5(list_tables_columns))
```

So the **outcome** is the following :

```
Time to read 1batch is :0.1856553554534912
Time to read 1batch is :0.173567533493042
Time to read 1batch is :0.1639997959136963
Time to read 1batch is :0.1889955997467041
Time to read 1batch is :0.14117860794067383
Time to read 1batch is :0.14899969100952148
Time to read 1batch is :0.14300036430358887
Time to read 1batch is :0.1419994831085205
Time to read 1batch is :0.14099979400634766
Time to read 1batch is :0.1399984359741211
Time to read 1batch is :0.1340029239654541
```

**Finish reading**:

```
Start taks : 0
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.440692663192749
Start taks : 1
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.23961353302001953
Start taks : 2
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.2606239318847656
Start taks : 3
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.2226719856262207
Start taks : 4
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.21300196647644043
Start taks : 5
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.22265386581420898
Start taks : 6
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.22600030899047852
Start taks : 7
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.28110337257385254
Start taks : 8
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.21700191497802734
Start taks : 9
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.24160361289978027
Start taks : 10
Time to write to file 1batch is :0.26999974250793457
```

It show the write part only starts when all the read are finnished.

Edit : I used a hack `await asyncio.sleep(0)` so the write process start immediatly my new code is now

```
async def writeToCsv_v6(list_tables_source):
     # start=time.time()
     connection_string='secret'
     for table in list_tables_source:
          list_columns=' ,'.join(f'"{item}"' for item in  list_tables_source[table] )
          #rows = cursor.execute('Select  '+list_columns+' from PUB."'+table+'"')
          reader = read_arrow_batches_from_odbc(
               query='Select  '+list_columns+' from PUB."'+table+'"',
               connection_string=connection_string,
               batch_size=200000,
               max_text_size=500,
          )         
          i=0
          list_tasks=[]
          for batch in reader:
            read_start=time.time()
             # Process arrow batches
            df = batch.to_pandas()
            read_stop=time.time()

            task=asyncio.create_task(write_to_parquet_v2(df,i))
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            list_tasks.append(task)
            print("Time to read "+str(i)+"batch is :"+str(read_stop-read_start))
            i+=1
          #   test
          #   if i>10:
               #    break
          print("finish read")
     await asyncio.gather(*list_tasks)
```

But now both the read and the write process are synchronous. Which doesn't help me much.

Comment: Your string is malformed, a closing quote is missing in `connection_string`, and your entire code following is considered part of the string, your code when copy pasted won't run, you should use double quotes because your string contains literal single quotes.

Comment: I just remove password for the post, my original code doesn't have this issue. And that's not the problem I describe. The odbc connection work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async program does not properly do "two things at the same time" like you are expecting - it is not multi-threading.

It just offers convenient ways of one program doing one thing wile it waits for another to finish - and you have *always* to tell when the code should pause to "awaiting" for something to happen - that is when other parts of the program can run.

That said, creating a task is not enough to put code in motion, it just schedules the code to be run - it is the call to `asyncio.gather` which will actually make the asyncio loop through all schedule tasks (and gather itself will return when the tasks it got as a parameter are done, but meanwhile it will cycle through all existing asyncio tasks: those which are a parameter to it and those who are not.

So, having the code write down to a file after each batch is just a matter of moving that `gather`  call to inside the for-loop that iterates through batches. That will write each 200.000 rows. Or,as you found out, sprinkling some `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in the middle of the code will also make the asyncio code loop through all created tasks once. **But** that alone can't make things run at the same time: both your `read_arrow_batches_from_odbc` and `write_to_parquet_v2` are *synchronous* functions which means: they won't delegate the execution to the asyncio event loop when they are waiting for I/O - they will simply run to completion: one batch fully gathered before writing to disk of that batch can take place, and only then the ODBC driver will fetch the next batch.

As can be seen, you could as well drop asyncio altogether from that code - that is the simpler way to get your job done - otherwise, it can be changed to work in a multi-threaded way, without many changes. But making it work properly in parallel with asyncio would require async versions of your ODBC driver, and for the parquet writer. What can be done to make it "look like asyncio" (and which a lot, maybe the majority of asyncio Python code does), is to run these tasks in other threads, and just use asyncio to coordinate the calls to fetch data. So a "fake" asyncio would be doable there - but possibly the resulting code would be more complex than just having one thread for getting data in, one to get data out, and coordinate things from the main thread.

(You'd need to write an asyncio generator to work as a wrapper to queue communication code to get the input data, for example. The wrapper is just an extra layer that is not needed)

I will re-write your code as simply multi-threaded instead. The "big" difference is each capability has to be written in a different function so that Python runs each function in a different thread. With asyncio code, from the botton-up, working asyncio libs, and so on, it is possible to make the fetching and writing datain a single function like you did: but that is not necessarily even mode readable, and most of time you will need helper functions anyway.

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

_sentinel = object()

def writeToCsv_v6(list_tables_source, data_queue):
    # start=time.time()
    connection_string='secret'
    for table in list_tables_source:
        list_columns=' ,'.join(f'"{item}"' for item in  list_tables_source[table] )
        #rows = cursor.execute('Select  '+list_columns+' from PUB."'+table+'"')
        reader = read_arrow_batches_from_odbc(
            query='Select  '+list_columns+' from PUB."'+table+'"',
            connection_string=connection_string,
            batch_size=200000,
            max_text_size=500,
        )         
        i=0
        for batch in reader:
            read_start=time.time()
            # Process arrow batches
            df = batch.to_pandas()
            read_stop=time.time()
            data_queue.put((df, i))
            print("Time to read "+str(i)+"batch is :"+str(read_stop-read_start))
            i+=1
            #   test
            #   if i>10:
                #    break
    queue.put(_sentinel)
    print("finish read")
    #await asyncio.gather(*list_tasks)
    
def writer_loop(data_queue):
    while True:
        data = queue.get()
        if data is _sentinel:
            break
        df, i  = data
        print(f"Writing batch {i} to disk")
        write_to_parquet_v2(df,i)
        
def coordinate(list_tables_source):
    data_queue = Queue()
    reader = Thread(target=writeToCsv_v6, args=(list_tables_source, data_queue))
    writer = Thread(target=loop, args=(data_queue,))
    reader.start()
    writer.start()
    reader.join()
    writer.join()
    print("all done")
```

(as a side note: Python does allow any amount of indentation to count as an indented block - but 4 spaces is pretty standard these days - it is nicer to people that will collaborate with you in your code)

Answer (score 1):

author of `arrow-odbc` here, from which you (my guess) import the function `read_arrow_batches_from_odbc`. In your situation it may be of interest to you that the reader has a method called `fetch_concurrently`, which much as the name suggests instantiates a system thread dedicated to fetching batches. See: https://arrow-odbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arrow_odbc.html#arrow_odbc.BatchReader.fetch_concurrently

This does not take away from the correctness of the answer of jsbueno. There is also a slight difference in what is achieved with utilizing this system thread vs. instantiating one in the application logic with Python.

From `arrow-odbc`'s perspective there are three stages in a pipeline:

Fetching int Fetch Buffer <--> Conversion of FetchBuffer content to Arrow Record Batch <--> Application Logic.

Calling `fetch_concurrently` will create a thread which exclusively works on the first stage. This is also a trade memory for speed thing. As a second fetch buffer needs to be allocated in order to achieve this.

Creating a thread in the application logic, like suggested in the answer from jsbueno will put the application logic in one thread and the conversion and fetching is still done in one thread calling `read_arrow_batches_from_odbc`.

Which one will turn out to be faster depends on your datascheme, database, etc.

You can also do both, having three threads in total. Likely only minimal speedup though, compared to any of the individual solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot : In the meantime I end up with a solution ( not optimal but working ) using threading and batch to start writing ( to the db ) as soon as a batch is done. Memory consumption is high but it work  ( Simplification of the code in answer bellow )

Answer (score 0):

@Markus Klein : This is the code I end up with :

```
  def ExtractData(list_tables_source):

      reader = read_arrow_batches_from_odbc(
           query=query,
           connection_string=connection_string,
           #Above 100 000 lines per batch we start having memory issue, but now the server have 12 Go insteand of 4 Go it might be interesting to rework that
           batch_size=100000,
           # THis is to fix an issue with Progress not correctly defining the size of each field so a field can be define as 10 char and you end up with 20 char in it.
           max_text_size=700,
      )
      i=0
      # This is a list of all the thread so we can keep track of them
      threads=list()
      # Define a list of partition for the bulk insert
      sqlpartitions=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
      #The cycle is here to create an infinite loop so when we reach the item 10 the next item to be gather is 1
      sqlpartitionscycle=cycle(sqlpartitions)
      read_start=time.time()
      for batch in reader:
        print("Start read task: "+str(i))
        #Next will gather the next one ,if it reach 10 the next one will be 1
        cycle_id=next(sqlpartitionscycle)
        print("Cycle is: "+str(cycle_id))     
        read_stop=time.time()
        print("   Time to read "+str(i)+" batch is :"+str(read_stop-read_start))
        print("Finnish reading starting writing task in seperate thread:"+str(i))
        # We rung the write in a separate thread so we can load the data into the DB while keep going with the extracting from ODBC
        thread=threading.Thread(target=write_to_csv_thread,args=(batch.to_pandas(),i,path+table,table,cycle_id,list_columns_mapped_pandas),name="Batch id"+str(i))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
        while(psutil.virtual_memory()[2]>90):
             print("------------Sleep for "+str(sleep_number_sec)+" secondes because memory usage is :"+str(psutil.virtual_memory()[2])+"% --------------")
             #This only sleep the "extract" thread, the other are not impacted
             time.sleep(sleep_number_sec)
             print("------------Finnish Sleep for "+str(sleep_number_sec)+" secondes because memory usage is :"+str(psutil.virtual_memory()[2])+"% --------------")
        i+=1
      print("finish read")
      read_start=time.time()
      #Joining the thread is utterly important in order to guarante the main thread doesn't exit before all sub thread finnished.
 for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
    print("Main    : before joining thread %d.", index)
    thread.join()
    print("Main    : thread %d done", index)


def write_to_csv_thread(datapacket: pd.DataFrame,itera: int,pathtofile,TableName,cycle_id,mapping_field_datatype):
 datapacket.to_csv(fullpath,mode='w',index=False,header=True,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
 del datapacket
 bulk_load_db(fullpath,TableName,itera)


def bulk_load_db(fullpath,TableName,itera):
 #Write and send bulk insert query to sql server

if __name__ =="__main__":
 start=time.time()
 extract = threading.Thread(target=ExtractData,args=(list_tables_columns,),name="extract")
 extract.start()
 # By joining the thread we make sur the extract thread finnish before the main finnish and close the program
 extract.join()
 end=time.time()
 print("Total time is :"+str(end-start))
```

It's not optimal, but it allows me to start writing to the database at the end of every batch. I will look into the fetch_concurrently method you mentioned.
Thanks a lot